How to check if I've been banned on GitHub?
How can I check if my account has been banned by a repo or org on GitHub?
I contributed several bug reports, feature requests, and a PR to a repo -- including some related to security & privacy/legal issues. I was respectful, but the owners of the repo reacted very defensively, a lot of users chimed-in, and now I can't comment.
On every GitHub issue in this org's repo that I checked (even the ones that I've created and are still "Open"), I see a lock icon and the text You can't perform this action at this time. at the bottom of the thread (where the comment textarea should be).
I suspect that I've been banned, but where can I go in the GitHub.com WUI (or API) to confirm this?

Have you tried reaching out to the repo, or going to GitHub (https://support.github.com/) directly?
